# Overriding types to prevent unsafe any calls

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have some tests in React Native using the react-test-renderer such as:

```
it('should keep login button disabled', async () => {                       
  const emailInput = root.findByProps({ testID: 'EmailInput' }); 
  const passwordInput = root.findByProps({ testID: 'PasswordInput' });  
  await act(async () => {                                                   
    await emailInput.props.onChangeText('abc'); 
    await passwordInput.props.onChangeText('abc');                          
  }); 
  const loginButton = root.findByProps({ testID: 'LoginButton' });          
    expect(loginButton.props.type).toBe('disabled');                          
  });
```

This works fine, but `@typescript-eslint` is complaining about `no-unsafe-call` because of the type declarations returned by ReactTestInstance: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-test-renderer/index.d.ts -- specifically, `ReactTestInstance` has `{ [propName: string]: any}`.

I generally want to keep this rule, so I want to avoid disabling it for every line.

I can create a type definition for `ReactTestInstance`, but when I do that, I also get "types of property `props` are incompatible." Same if I use casting.

Is there any way to override library types? Beyond that, are there any other suggestions to handle the unsafe type in this way?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution here is probably going to be to cast `props` to correct type, rather than casting `ReactTestInstance` to a custom type. Like so:

```js
await (emailInput.props as EmailInputProps).onChangeText('abc');
```

While casting `ReactTestInstance` is possible (you just need cast to `unknown` first, e.g. `... as unknown as MyCustomType`), casting each of the props to their correct types instead will give you more accurate types overall. You probably have a type for those props easily available already anyway.

Comment: This does work, but then I need to cast `props` each time. Is there a possible solution where I can declare the type at the top level so I don't have to cast every instance?